# How to read procfs file?

Tags: c, linux

I tried to read the /proc/modules using standard c functions:

```
FILE *pfile;
int sz;
pfile = fopen( "/proc/modules", "r" );
fseek( pfile, 0, SEEK_END );
sz = ftell( pfile );
rewind( ftell );
```

But my problem is ftell give me 0 value. So I can't read the contents of the file since I have a zero length. Is there another way that I can get the size of the file that I want to read?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not have a size. However, you can read parts of it until you reach end-of-file.

Comment: Exactly. A "file" in /proc will always return size=0 but if you go ahead and read it anyway you will get data.

Comment: The app gives me Segmentation Fault when I am looking for the EOF using fgetc.

Comment: Maybe it's better to open a new question about the segfault, with the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3):

/proc files are dynamically created when you read them, so they cannot have a size.

I stand corrected. Some /proc files do indeed have a size, as adobriyan has noted on a comment to Sjoerd's answer. (Is that Alexey Dobriyan of Linux Kernel fame?)

As for how to read the file using fgetc, this works:

```
int c;
while ( (c = fgetc(pfile)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

And your program is segfaulting because you're trying to rewind ftell.

Comment: Is there any possible way that I can read the dynamic data of the procfs precisely. I did what Sjoerd suggested using fgetc but it gives me a segmentation fault.